# After selecting check box Instead of Tick symbol need X in html

Tags: html, css

After selecting the check box in a form currently I am getting tick symbol as default. but here I need X(cross Mark) . Do I need put a class for that and have to apply any styling for that class.This is the simple form I am trying

```
 <input type="checkbox"> Selected 1st element
 <input type="checkbox"> selected 2nd element
```

Comment: Just one suggestion : If you will use material js with angular, you will feel better with this. Refer this just: https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/checkbox

Comment: yea I have referred it earlier only . but in that all are tick symbol by default. but i need a different one

Comment: Actually can't got you , can you please elaborate?

Answer (score 10):

Better use image or try changing  `content: "X";`

you can properly change unicode of ticks to any other symbol :https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_mark

```css
input[type="checkbox"]{
    -webkit-appearance: initial;
    appearance: initial;
    background: gray;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    border: none;
    position: relative;
}
input[type="checkbox"]:checked {
    background: red;
}
input[type="checkbox"]:checked:after {
    /* Heres your symbol replacement */
    content: "X";
    color: #fff;
    /* The following positions my tick in the center, 
     * but you could just overlay the entire box
     * with a full after element with a background if you want to */
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    -moz-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    /*
     * If you want to fully change the check appearance, use the following:
     * content: " ";
     * width: 100%;
     * height: 100%;
     * background: blue;
     * top: 0;
     * left: 0;
     */
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" />
```

Comment: Yeah I think its not working I tried it earlier itself

Comment: @PradeepRamisetti its working. For changing symbols include font-awesome.css.

Comment: Yea its working @Shivkumar . thank you for your inputs

Answer (score 6):

Try this, I will provide you a fiddle too,

```css
input[type=checkbox].css-checkbox { position: absolute;  overflow: hidden;  clip: rect(0 0 0 0);  height:1px;  width:1px;  margin:-1px;  padding:0; border:0; } 
input[type=checkbox].css-checkbox + label.css-label { padding-left:20px; height:15px;  display:inline-block; line-height:15px; background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position: 0 0; font-size:15px; vertical-align:middle; cursor:pointer; } 
input[type=checkbox].css-checkbox:checked + label.css-label { background-position: 0 -15px; }  .css-label{ background-image:url(http://csscheckbox.com/checkboxes/lite-x-red.png); }
```

```html
<form>
<input id="demo_box_2" class="css-checkbox" type="checkbox" />
<label for="demo_box_2" name="demo_lbl_2" class="css-label">Selected Option</label>
<input id="demo_box_3" class="css-checkbox" type="checkbox" />
<label for="demo_box_3" name="demo_lbl_3" class="css-label">Selected Option</label>
</form>
```

**Try the snippet**

[check the Fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/twrqkudd/3/)

Comment: But its working for only one selection. If we are having multiple its not working. what ever we selected in the below its reflecting for first option itself

Comment: yeah . trying to changing the color of X