# custom check box: how to check whether check box is checked or not

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have made custom check box by using this :

[enter link description here](https://jsfiddle.net/twrqkudd/3/)

also available on stackoverflow: [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40123695/after-selecting-check-box-instead-of-tick-symbol-need-x-in-html)

but i am trying to check whether box is crossed check or not but i am failed bcz jquery is nt showing anything.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var ckbox = $('#demo_box_2');

    $('#demo_box_2').on('click',function () {
        if (ckbox.is(':checked')) {
            alert('You have Checked it');
        } else {
            alert('You Un-Checked it');
        }
    });
});
```

```css
input[type=checkbox].css-checkbox { position: absolute;  overflow: hidden;  clip: rect(0 0 0 0);  height:1px;  width:1px;  margin:-1px;  padding:0; border:0; } 
input[type=checkbox].css-checkbox + label.css-label { padding-left:20px; height:15px;  display:inline-block; line-height:15px; background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position: 0 0; font-size:15px; vertical-align:middle; cursor:pointer; } 
input[type=checkbox].css-checkbox:checked + label.css-label { background-position: 0 -15px; }  .css-label{ background-image:url(http://csscheckbox.com/checkboxes/lite-x-red.png); }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
<input id="demo_box_2" class="css-checkbox" type="checkbox" />
<label for="demo_box_2" name="demo_lbl_2" class="css-label">Selected Option</label>
</form>
```

i dont know where i am wrong whether i am passing id to jquery correctly but still fail to understand.

Comment: Hi, your code seems to work perfectly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use JQuery `.is(":checked")` to do so, like so:

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").click(function() {
  var msg = "";
  $("input[type=checkbox]").each(function() {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
      msg += "#" + $(this).attr("id") + " is checked!\n";
    } else {
      msg += "#" + $(this).attr("id") + " is NOT checked!\n";
    }
  });
  alert(msg);
});
```

[Here is the **JSFiddle demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/u60qerdm/)

Comment: thnx and sorry for late reply. was in class room

Answer (score 3):

your code is working, although I made some changes, used `$(this)` instead of `id` selector.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    

    $('#demo_box_2').on('click',function () {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            alert('You have Checked it');
        } else {
            alert('You Un-Checked it');
        }
    });
});
```

```css
input[type=checkbox].css-checkbox { position: absolute;  overflow: hidden;  clip: rect(0 0 0 0);  height:1px;  width:1px;  margin:-1px;  padding:0; border:0; } 
input[type=checkbox].css-checkbox + label.css-label { padding-left:20px; height:15px;  display:inline-block; line-height:15px; background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position: 0 0; font-size:15px; vertical-align:middle; cursor:pointer; } 
input[type=checkbox].css-checkbox:checked + label.css-label { background-position: 0 -15px; }  .css-label{ background-image:url(http://csscheckbox.com/checkboxes/lite-x-red.png); }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
<input id="demo_box_2" class="css-checkbox" type="checkbox" />
<label for="demo_box_2" name="demo_lbl_2" class="css-label">Selected Option</label>
</form>
```