# Dropdown select with delete option next to each option value

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I need to implement a drop-down which has a delete 'X' option next to each option item. Somewhat like the image shown below.
The drop-down is populated dynamically and I need a way that does not inlvolve using list as an alternative.

EDIT: The icons next to each dropdown item refers to 'Edit'/'Delete'

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot put a checkbox into the usual `<select>` or multi-select HTML element.

However, [here is another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17714705/how-to-use-checkbox-inside-select-option) where several good options are discussed.

This looks like the most useful and best suited to your purpose:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/27547021/1447509

And here is an example of how to change the default checkmark to an X:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/40123793/1447509

Sources:

[How to use Checkbox inside Select Option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17714705/how-to-use-checkbox-inside-select-option)

[After selecting check box Instead of Tick symbol need X in html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40123695/after-selecting-check-box-instead-of-tick-symbol-need-x-in-html)

### UPDATE:

Given that you need both the HTML markup *and* the javascript to make it do what you want, you have two (possibly 3) steps to do:

1. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27547021/1447509) provides a good example of how to create the custom-rolled `<select>` control.
2. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40123793/1447509) shows you how to replace the checkbox created in step 1 with an icon/image of your choosing.
3. The javascript to remove the x'd `<option>` is very simple:

```
    $(this).closest('option').remove();
```

4. *IF you also need to save these results*, then you also need to learn:

4a. Server-side SESSIONS (so that each user's customizations are saved *for them*)

4b. A login system, so you know for which user to save the current customizations.

4c. Just the basics of how to use a back-end database, such as MySQL/MariaDB, in which to store the user customizations.

4d. AJAX - so you can schlep info to the back-end for insertion into the database without refreshing (or navigating away from) the current page. AJAX replaces the ancient and no-longer-used `<form>` construct. Frankly, once you've used AJAX a couple of times, you'll never go back. Totally easy.

---

***If you are in a bind and need someone to create the whole thing for you, I refer you to [one of these websites](https://www.insidermonkey.com/blog/10-best-freelance-websites-for-programmers-513415/?singlepage=1) - I have used such services myself and can recommend them.***

Comment: Hi, Thanks for taking time to reply.
However, I am not looking for a multiselect(checkbox in a dropdown).
But, a way to 'EDIT' / 'DELETE' the items in the dropdown.

Comment: So, beside each item (`<option>`, to be exact) in the select control you want a checkbox (or other clickable element) that will allow you to remove that `option` *from the select control*? If so, I think step 1 is done in the above answer, and step two is just a bit of javascript that will remove that element. Is that correct?

Comment: My apologies if the description was confusing.
I DO NOT want checkboxes at all really.
The 'cross' and 'pencil' icons next to each "option" correspond to 'delete' and 'edit' respectively, and I want to be able to delete the option when clicked specifically on the cross for a particular option(For the purposes of simplicity you could ignore the 'edit' feature as that warrants more discussion)
Hopefully, that made more sense.

Comment: Do you already have the HTML written for the `<select>` control that includes the cross and pencil icons?

Comment: I do not. The above is a mock up I received from the Web Designer and I kinda have to stick to the design work. (If it were up to me, I'd have gone for a listview and make it look and work like a customized select.)